# JavaScript forms with localStorage on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, forms

I have two questions regarding this problem that I'm having:

1 - When I do `if (nickname in localStorage)` is it valid? Because everytime I run the code it doesn't work.

2 - I'm trying to validate forms in more than one page, however everytime  I want to save a nickname or whatever it is it saves where another was saved. I've tried adding a countable variable, but it still doesn't work. What is the best way to do so?

Here's my code for two of my three forms:

```
var k = 0;
function main() {
     var buttonregister = document.getElementById("next");
     var buttonlogin = document.getElementById("nextlogin");
     var buttonsignin = document.getElementById("nextsignin");

     if(buttonregister != null) {
         buttonregister.addEventListener("click", createaccount);
     } else if (buttonlogin != null) {
         buttonlogin.addEventListener("click", submit);
     }
}

function submit() {
    var login = document.login;
    var nickname = login.nickname.value;
    if (nickname in localStorage) {
        alert('The nickname ' + nickname + ' is already in use.');
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("username"+k, nickname);  
        localStorage.setItem("password"+k, "");
        localStorage.setItem("email"+k, ""); 
        k++;
    }

    login.reset();
}

function createaccount() {
    var register = document.register;
    var nickname = register.nickname.value;
    var password = register.password.value;
    var email = register.email.value;

    if (nickname in localStorage) {
        alert('The nickname ' + nickname + ' is already in use.')
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("username"+k, nickname);
        localStorage.setItem("password"+k, password);
        localStorage.setItem("email"+k, email);
        k++;
    }

    register.reset();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {main()});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The `in` operator returns the key, not the value. So you are asking if localStorage contains a key that is equal to the value stored in `nickname`. I don't think that is your intent based upon the `alert()` that follows.

Additionally, you never set a `nickname` localStorage property, so the test is moot anyway.

2. Indexing based upon a counter isn't necessarily a good practice here since order cannot be guaranteed. There are many ways to solve this problem. One simple way would be using a prefix such as the page title, form name or something similar.